# Proof of recursion proof.

Tags: logic

Let $P_n, n\in\mathbb N$ a property. We suppose that $P_{n_0}$ is true for a certain $n_0\in \mathbb N$ and that $P_n$ true implies $P_{n+1}$ true for all $n\geq n_0$. Prove that $P_n$ is true for all $n\geq n_0$.

**Attempts**

Suppose it's no true, and Let $m>n_0$ s.t. $P_m$ is false. Let $A=\{n\mid P_n\ false\}\subset \mathbb N$. Since $\mathbb N$ is well ordered and that $A\neq\emptyset$, there is a minimal element $k=\min A$. In particular, $P_{k-1}$ is true and $P_{k}$ is wrong which is a contradiction with the fact that $P_{n}\implies P_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Therefore $P_n$ true for all $n$.

**Question :** Is it true ? My problem is that I don't understand where I used the fact that $P_{n_0}$ true.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no $n$ such that $P_n$ true, then $0=k=\min A$ and thus $P_{k-1}$ wouldn't have any sense.

Comment: We're given that $P_{n_0}$ is true.

Comment: @Kevin: You should read the question ;-)

Comment: It's ambiguous, but seeing as the OP wrote "we suppose" before the imperative "Prove that...", I read it as a given rather than an assumption.

Comment: @Kevin : it's not ambiguous at all, and the question is precisely : *Where did I used the fact that $P_{n_0}$ is true*. An I answered to this question.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You should *answer* the question (with a "yes" or "no").